# How are async void event handlers called in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, async-await

If I declare my event handlers as `async void`, will they be called synchronously or asynchronously by the .NET framework?

I.e., given the following code:

```
async void myButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   do stuff
   await longRunning()
   do more stuff
}
```

Can I be sure that the "do stuff" line will be executed on the GUI thread?

Comment: Please provide a comment for the downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Event handlers will be called synchronously and doesn't wait(await) till the event handler completes, but waits till the event handler returns.

If previous sentence was confusing enough, I'll try to explain it clear. Asynchronous methods completes when all the await points are executed and the end of the method body has reached or any return statement is executed(Ignoring the exception). But asynchronous method returns as soon as you hit the first await statement for the `Task` which is not yet completed. In other words asynchronous method can return several times but can complete only once.

So now we know when does a asynchronous method completes and returns. Event handler will assume your method has completed as soon as it returns not when it actually completes.

As soon as your event handler reaches first `await` statement, it will return, if there are more methods attached to same event handler, it will continue executing them **without** waiting for the asynchronous method to complete.

Yes, `do stuff` will be executed in UI thread if the UI thread fires the event and yes `do more stuff` will also be executed in UI thread as long as `longRunning().ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't called.

Comment: Thanks, your first sentence was enough for me :)

Comment: @Eyvind Not all people are smart. That's why I explained in another words assuming it will help future readers :)

Comment: I think the wording in your last paragraph is slightly misleading; `do more stuff` will execute in the UI thread even if there's a call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` within `longRunning`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Removed that part. I guess I'm missing something here, need to work on that part. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenCleary So the scope of `ConfigureAwait(false)` is only within the state machine in which the `ConfigureAwait` was called am I right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes. I think of it like this: each method is independent; it captures its own context at `await` and resumes in that context. So if a method further down the call stack doesn't resume in its context, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, that cleared up another somewhat confusing point for me!

Answer (score 6):

They will be invoked just as any other non-`async-await` method is invoked:

```
Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Because this specific event handler is an `async` method the call would run synchronously until an `await` is reached and the rest would be a continuation. **That means that `do stuff` is executed synchronously on the GUI thread**. The caller then moves on without the knowledge that the `async` operation hasn't completed yet.

`do more stuff` would also be executed on the GUI thread, but for a different reason. The `SynchronizationContext` in a GUI environment makes sure the continuations would be posted to the single GUI thread, unless you explicitly tell it not to with `await longRunning().ConfigureAwait(false)`